# "Official" R Minimum System Requirements

Tags: r

I am currently developing a solution in R and I need to know the system requirements for R on a windows machine for documentation purposes.

It's a question beyond "would R run in my machine", since I need to know the exact specifics. I know for a fact that it already runs without any problem, but I need to document this requirements for the Administrator in the IT team.

Thank you so much for your collaboration!

Comment: There probably aren't any (beyond OS version).

Comment: R + Rtools, preferably 64 bit OS. More memory is better, depending on the type of work you plan to do. Ask IT how to deal with new R versions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware requirements, not about programming.  It's also going to be very difficult to answer; R doesn't *have* an official requirements policy as far as I know. Ironically, [this FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-run-under-Windows-Vista_003f) about "Does R run on my Windows version?" dates from when Windows 7/8 were the *new* versions of Windows ...

Comment: My tests (from earlier this year) on Windows, macOS and Ubuntu showed that `R --vanilla` (as an aside, why is there no `--chocolate` option?) consumes 36MB-42MB RAM (dependent upon the compilation options used to build R). That's kinda useless info since it's unlikely whatever you're running with R is going to eat far more than that. You should be quite capable of determining the disk space consumed by a default install. 32-bit or 64-bit processors are required. That should be enough for your apparently very novice IT admins.

Answer (score 1):

From An Introduction to R (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html)

> --max-mem-size=N
>   (Windows only) Specify a limit for the amount of memory to be used both for R objects and working areas. This is set by default to the smaller of the amount of physical RAM in the machine and for 32-bit R, 1.5Gb26, and must be between 32Mb and the maximum allowed on that version of Windows.

Note, this is specific to Windows machines.  I haven't seen anything regarding other operating systems.  I've never seen anything about processors or other hardware either.

as far as I can tell, if you have a computer with a processor and at least 32 Mb or RAM, it will run R (no guarantees on how well).